# what happens when multiple case conditions holds good with in row_number?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

how does case works i can see all the conditions are validated and sorting based all all true condition, doesnt it exists upon the first match???

```
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 

                            CASE   WHEN @SortColumn = N'DataUsage' AND @SortAsc = 0 THEN t.DataUsage END DESC,
                            CASE   WHEN @SortColumn = N'OSVersion' AND @SortAsc = 1 THEN t.OSMajorVersion END DESC  ,
                            case   WHEN @SortColumn = N'OSVersion' AND @SortAsc = 1 THEN t.OSMinorVersion END DESC,
                            case   WHEN @SortColumn = N'OSVersion' AND @SortAsc = 1 THEN t.OSBuildNumber END DESC
                        ) myRow
```

question is on N'OSVersion'

Answer (score 0):

You have four different `case` statements.  So each one gets executed.

It is hard to say what you really want, but perhaps you want to combine these into 1?

```
        (CASE WHEN @SortColumn = N'DataUsage' AND @SortAsc = 0 THEN t.DataUsage
              WHEN @SortColumn = N'OSVersion' AND @SortAsc = 1 THEN t.OSMajorVersion
              WHEN @SortColumn = N'OSVersion' AND @SortAsc = 1 THEN t.OSMinorVersion
              WHEN @SortColumn = N'OSVersion' AND @SortAsc = 1 THEN t.OSBuildNumber
         END) DESC
```

Comment: what is need is to sort by osversion . so when my @sortcolumn is 'osversion' all 3 case condition will be satisfied. My question is will the rownumber would act as ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OSMajorVersion DESC ,OSMinorVersion DESC,OSBuildNumber DESC)